# How to import two values that are in the same excel field separated by a comma

Tags: apex, data-loader, csv, import

I just got an .csv file that i need to import into my sandbox as a custom object, it looks like this:

[image]

The value that is on the **left side of the comma** should be stored as a field (called Location).

And the value that is on the **right side of the comma** should be stored as a another field (called Country).

There are around 7k of these records, **what would be the optimal aproach to import this?**

Should I go with data loader and then try to divde those fields with an apex class? if that so... how?

Im a newbie, so I apologize for doing this dumb question.
Thank You!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Text to Columns feature in Excel to divide the data into separate columns *before* you do your import.

As a general rule, it is almost always easier to perform data transformations before you move the data into Salesforce.